# Additional Command Line Argument in VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio for C++ 2017, and I need to set the command line argument /DEFAULTLIB:. In the documentation, it says that I have to go to Linker/Command Line and put the argument in Additional Options, however, I have put it and the following error still raises:

`error: LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/DEFAULTLIB:'`

Linker/Command Line/Additional Options looks like this:

`/DEFAULTLIB:"dlltest.lib"` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Drop the quotes: `/DEFAULTLIB:dlltest.lib`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the same error still raises with ```/DEFAULTLIB:dlltest.lib```. Do I have to enable Additional Options or something like that somewhere?